# Mismatching colours on two layers (ggplot2 v0.9)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot where geom_paths connect some geom_points. Both should be in the same colour but for some reason, there is often a mismatch between the two. This happens when there is missing data at a particular place.

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
nCategory<-5
nItem<-6
df<-data.frame(category=rep(LETTERS[1:nCategory],1,each=nItem),
           item=paste("Item#",rep(1:nItem,nCategory,each=1),sep=''),
           value=rep(1:nItem,nCategory,each=1)+runif(nCategory*nItem)*0.8)

df<-df[sample(nrow(df),20),] # shuffle the data frame and remove some data

df<-arrange(df,category,item)
p<-ggplot(df)
p<-p+geom_point(aes(x=value,y=category,colour=item),size=3)
p<-p+geom_path(aes(x=value,y=category,group=item,colour=item),size=1.5)
p
```

[image: mismatched colours]

As far as I can tell, this doesn't happen if there is no data missing or at least if there is no missing data for the first point of the path (starting at 'A'). In that case, connecting lines and points have the same colour.

I tried to fix the colour scale but this didn't change anything.

How can I end up with the same colours for the points and their connecting lines?

EDIT: I'm using ggplot2 0.9. It doesn't happen with ggplot2 0.8.9.

Session Info:

```
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices datasets  stats     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.7.1    stringr_0.6   ggplot2_0.9.0 RMySQL_0.8-0  DBI_0.2-5    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.1       fortunes_1.4-2     grid_2.14.1        MASS_7.3-16        memoise_0.1       
 [8] munsell_0.3        proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.1     scales_0.1.0       tools_2.14.1
```

Comment: Your sample code produces correct results on my machine, i.e the points and paths are the same colour.  What is the result of `sessionInfo()` on your machine?  In other words, what version of `ggplot2` and other packages are you using?

Comment: good point, I'm on ggplot 0.9, forgot to mention that.

Comment: When I run your script (and make changes to it) I still get the same color for the points and the lines. That is, I am unable to replicate what I see in your ggplot.

Comment: That's right, I've just checked and it does work with ggplot2 0.8.9.

Comment: This is a bug in `geom_path` and will be fixed in the official release being planed on March. https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commit/4203f765752adf31a58b5931edaa2d6cc2e2ac51#R/geom-path-.r-P26

Comment: I see, thank you. Looking forward to that. I'll revert to 0.8.9 in the meantime.

Comment: In your case, simply you can get a correct plot by ordering the data by `arrange(df,item,category)` -- note that the order of argument is important.